# Output of pandas head function is not displayed

Tags: python, pandas, head

I'm doing a `pandas` training and on the second lab i'm supposed to open a file and print the first 5 rows. The problem is that from the code below I only get the "Done" printed, but it isn't printing the output from `df.head()`. I cannot find a reason why. ¿Any tips?

```
import pandas as pd

filename="https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning- 
databases/autos/imports-85.data"

hs = ["symboling","normalized-losses","make","fuel-type","aspiration", 
   "num-of-doors","body-style", "drive-wheels","engine-location","wheel-base", "length","width","height","curb-weight","engine-type", "num-of-cylinders", "engine-size","fuel-system","bore","stroke","compression-ratio","horsepower",
     "peak-rpm","city-mpg","highway-mpg","price"]

df = pd.read_csv(filename, names=hs)
print("Done")
df.head()
```

Comment: Just noticed the code works just OK from the CLI. The problem is when executing lab2.py.

Comment: if you execute on jupter notebook it shows output as html content. but on IDE in order to displat on console you need to use print.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to print the df.head() too.

```
print(df.head())
```

Comment: Ran into this today. The pandas Getting Started docs for "coming from SQL" assume you're using a notebook. I saw nothing in the output because I was just making a script. I'm not using notebooks yet.